# Run only method from .py file using crontab

Tags: python, cron

There is .py file with multipe methods in it.
I want to run a specific method from that file every 15 minutes.

I can edit crontab on server and something like following :

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/my/file.py
```

But this will run entire python file. How do I run only method of that file ?

Comment: Make a new file that only imports the relevant function and executes it.

Comment: `*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/python -c "import file; the_method_you_want()"` - this will only work if `file.py` is globally importable (ie, is somewhere in `PYTHONPATH`); otherwise you'll need to use @jordanm's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one file with 2 function file1.py

```
def something():
    print ('something')
def somethingElse():
    print ('something else')
```

another file file2.py

```
import file1
file1.something()
```

you can setup cron on the file2.py

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, it a class / instance method, I would do something like below :

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/my/file.py <<some_param>>
```

now in file.py

```
class A(object):
   def foo1(self):
     pass
   def foo2(self):
     pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
   if len(sys.argv > 1):
      option = sys.argv[1]
      if option == <<some_param>>:
         obj = A()
         obj.foo1()
```

If its simple `@staticmethod`, @Burhan's comment would work fine! :)